# Inject Custom Store into Application

Tags: vue.js

[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) allows you to inject the store into your root instance, making it accessible via `this.$store` in all child components.

**Without Vuex, is it possible to inject a custom store implementation into child components?**

e.g.

```
// main.js
let app = new Vue({router, store, ...App}).$mount("#flightdeck-app")
export { app, store, router }

// SomeComponent.vue
export default {
  name: "Overview",

  components: { "credentials": Credentials },

  computed: {
    count() {
      // injected store; is currently undefined.
      return this.$store.state.items.length
    }
  },
```

Attempting to access `this.$store` results in undefined in child components, as Vuex seemingly has additional hooks to make this happen.

Comment: If you are not using Vuex, what is store in main.js, how will you get this.$store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a custom plugin for vue that register an initialize your custom store (or anything, I'll create a logger object just for demonstration).

For example you could have

```
//myLogger.js
export default {

  install(Vue, options) {
     function log(type, title, text) {
       console.log(`[${type}] ${title} - ${text}`);
     }

     Vue.prototype.$log = {
       error(title, text) { log('danger', title, text) },
       success(title, text) { log('success', title, text) },
       log
     }
  }
}
```

Before your main Vue instance tell to register your plugin

```
//main.js
import Logger from './path/to/myLogger';

Vue.use(Logger);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Now you can call `this.$log` on any child component

```
//myComponent.vue
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    Save() {
      this.$log.success('Transaction saved!');
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps, for more detail please see [Vue plugins documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

Comment: This worked great. I was able to inject a simple `StoreService` into the application by simply having `Vue.prototype.$store = this.store` in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Just use in your components files:

```
import store from './vuex/store.js'
```

1. Place your store in separate file to get it clear.
2. Import store to every component where you need store.